# Open form and set unbound ComboBox to specific value

Tags: ms-access, openargs

**ISSUE**

I have two forms:

- `frmForms`
- `frmDockRental`

I have two controls associated with this issue:

- `lstOwners` on `frmForms` (*unbound*)
- `cboOwner` on `frmDockRental` (*unbound*)

The second form (`frmDockRental`) is opened using different listboxes located on `frmForms` (See Image).  I have one such listbox that's giving me grief.  It is a filtered list of contacts that when double-clicked it should be opening `frmDockRental` to a *NEW* record and set `cboOwner`, which is unbound, to a specific item in the list.  The same item listed in `lstOwners` from `frmForms`.

**CODE**

After a lot of fiddling, I came up with this - except nothing happens at all.

```
Private Sub lstOwners_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
On Error GoTo lstOwners_DblClick_Err

    On Error Resume Next
    If (Form.Dirty) Then
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    End If
    If (MacroError.Number <> 0) Then
        Beep
        MsgBox MacroError.Description, vbOKOnly, ""
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmDockRental", acNormal, "", "", acFormAdd, acDialog, Me.lstOwners
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name

lstOwners_DblClick_Exit:
    Exit Sub

lstOwners_DblClick_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume lstOwners_DblClick_Exit
End Sub
```

And on `frmDockRental`, this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error GoTo Form_Load_Err

    DoCmd.MoveSize , , 5.3 * 1440, 5.2 * 1440
'    If (IsNull(OpenArgs)) Then
'        Exit Sub
'    End If
    If Me.OpenArgs <> vbNullString Then
        Me.cboOwner = Me.OpenArgs
    End If
    If (Not IsNull(OpenArgs)) Then
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec
    End If

Form_Load_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Form_Load_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Form_Load_Exit
End Sub
```

I figured OpenArgs would be the best method to accomplish this, but it just doesn't work.  Nothing at all happens.  No errors, just nothing.
[image: frmForms]

**EDIT:**

Here's an image of the step debugging.

[image: Step Debugging]

Comment: Have you step debugged? Use Me.Dirty instead for Form.Dirty.

Comment: You set breakpoint and step debugged? The procedure doesn't even start? Disable the `On Error` lines and see what happens.

Comment: Image shows code is running. I just noticed `Exit Sub` just before OpenForm line. Code never gets to open form. Suggest you remove that line. For VBA error handler review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-23a.html

Comment: Oops!  Fixed that.  ``frmDockRental`` still doesn't assign ``cboOwner`` a value.  When it opens, it opens blank.  I have a feeling it's something wrong with one or both of these two lines of code: ``DoCmd.OpenForm "frmDockRental", acNormal, "", "", acFormAdd, acDialog, Me.lstOwners`` which opens the form, and ``If Me.OpenArgs <> vbNullString Then Me.cboOwner = Me.OpenArgs End If `` which is on the form load. - EDIT: Deleted unnecessary comments.

Comment: So does OpenArgs have the listbox value? Again, step debug. Does the `Me.cboOwner = Me.OpenArgs` line ever execute?

Comment: Figured it out - sigh.  I had a blurb in there stating ``If (Not IsNull (OpenArgs)`` sending me to a new record.  Commented that out and it worked.  That's what I get for trying too many things at once.  Thanks @June7!